Can I extend a hallway circuit to add a GFCI outlet in a bathroom?
I'm planning to add an outlet in a bathroom. I can't wire it myself from the existing outlet since there is a door between it and the planned outlet.
There is an outlet on the opposite side of the wall from where I'd like to add it. I plan to just cut a hole in the wall, and daisy chain from that. That room is an entryway room and has a 20A circuit with a 15A outlet. If I daisy chain from it, besides ensuring that the new outlet is GFCI, are there any other things to consider / look out for?
Also, even though they will both be 15A outlets, I plan to run 12/2 romex between the two because I have some on hand. That shouldn't be an issue, right?
Thanks in advance for all the advice.

The 20 amp circuit requires all wiring to handle 20 amps, regardless of outlet ampacity.

@JonCuster, answers go down there. Your comment is exactly what should be in an answer.

Marc J, be sure you understand the flaw in your thinking there. These will not be "15A outlets". They'll be every bit capable of delivering 20 Amps, regardless of their rating (which involves a bit of a loophole in code). Any wiring must be able to support that. While you stated that yours will, you implied that this was discretionary. It isn't.

Ah, that makes sense.  The power coming through from the breaker is 20A so all wires need to be able to handle that, regardless of what the output device is. Thanks @isherwood

New bathroom outlets/receptacles must be for the bathroom room only.  So panel to bathroom outlet is good, outlet from hallway/another room is bad.

TL;DR No
From NEC 2020 210.11(C)(3):

210.11(C)(3) Bathroom Branch Circuits. In addition to the number of branch circuits required by other parts of this section, one or more 120-volt, 20-ampere branch circuit shall be provided to supply bathroom(s) receptacle outlet(s) required by 210.52(D) and any countertop and similar work surface receptacle outlets. Such circuits shall have no other outlets.
Exception: Where the 20-ampere circuit supplies a single bathroom, outlets for other equipment within the same bathroom shall be permitted to be supplied in accordance with 210.23(A)(1) and (A)(2).

In plain English this means: you can have one or more 20A circuits that feed all bathroom receptacles or one 20A circuit per bathroom, which can then also feed lights and other things besides receptacles in that bathroom, but you can't share those circuit(s) with any other rooms.
If you add a bathroom receptacle to a currently external circuit then you have violated this rule because it now becomes a bathroom circuit that has other receptacles outside the bathroom.
It is quite common to have combined circuits in older houses, and those are grandfathered provided they met code when originally installed. But you can't add new receptacles that would violate current code.

To clarify the 15A/20A issue:

A 15A circuit can have 14 AWG or larger (including 12 AWG) wire
A 20A circuit can have 12 AWG or larger wire, but no 14 AWG
A 15A circuit powering receptacles can have any number of 15A receptacles
A 20A circuit powering receptacles can have any number of 20A receptacles or 2 or more 15A receptacles. A standard duplex counts as two receptacles in this context even though it is a single "device". It can also have a mix of 15A and 20A receptacles.

Any 15A receptacle is designed to handle 20A pass-through to other parts of the circuit. And a 15A duplex receptacle on a 20A circuit can easily have 20A (e.g., 15A in the top receptacle, 5A in the bottom).
The result of this rule is that in residential installations it is very common to have 15A receptacles on all 15A and 20A circuits. That is because very few consumer items actually need a 20A receptacle (a bit of chicken and egg problem for historical reasons) and using 15A everywhere keeps inventory (for builders/electricians) simpler. 20A receptacles are much more common in commercial buildings.

Thank you for that layman's explanation, and for the citation. I suppose I will find a way to feed the new outlet from the same circuit.

In the US, a wiring to a 20 amp circuit breaker must be all 12 gauge or bigger wires. This is regardless of what the socket is rated for, and even at the end of a wiring run.
Consider that someone else will come along in the future, note that the circuit is a 20 amp breaker, and "upgrade" your 15 amp outlet to a 20 amp outlet. Now any 14 gauge feeders would be a fire hazard.
